# How to fix the Deprecated webOnlyWarmupEngine and webOnlySetPluginHandler API issues in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, vscode-debugger

I have an issue in flutter web.
This is the issues on debug console.

1. The webOnlyWarmupEngine API is deprecated and will be removed in a
   future release. Please use `bootstrapEngine` from `dart:ui_web`
   instead.
2. The webOnlySetPluginHandler API is deprecated and will be removed in
   a future release. Please use `setPluginHandler` from `dart:ui_web`
   instead.
3. The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and
   will be removed in a future release. Please use
   `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.

Flutter web is working now, but my client really don't want to make any issues.
If you are available to help me, please assist me.

Comment: Hi. I think the issue is related to this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133069. The fixes is available in the latest flutter hotfixes https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#3133-september-7-2023

Comment: @iqfareez I checked github issue page, but it has no proper solution. What is the best solution for this issue do you think?

Answer (score 1):

it is related to SDK version for me it is fixed by running the command `flutter upgrade --force` in the terminal and then reopen the visual studio

Answer (score 0):

flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit

Comment: Is it for only web version?

Comment: Yeah, it runs with this command but still doesn't work correctly I found

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue use below code

library: import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

```
if (kIsWeb) {
setPathUrlStrategy();
runApp(
  MyApp(),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I was using **SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle** in the main method and it is for mobile apps. That's why my app was not running on the web. By applying the web check condition I resolved my issue. I hope it will also help you

```
Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 // If the platform is web then if block will not be executed 

 if(!kIsWeb) {
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
     statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
     statusBarBrightness:
       Platform.isAndroid ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
     statusBarIconBrightness:
       Platform.isAndroid ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
   ));
 }

 runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's related to this:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/130137

The current quickfix (if you don't need current beta or master upgrades) is changing your flutter channel to stable using:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

commands on the terminal

Comment: @DevConductor how did you fix this issue? I upgraded to Flutter 3.13.0 today on stable and I'm getting the issue you described.

Comment: same here, still getting the same issue....(Flutter 3.13.0, channel = stable)

Comment: @DevConductor Seriously, if you fixed it, please share your fix. Even if it doesn't apply to a particular environment, it may be useful. I have the same issue after switching to Kubuntu 22.03 and it's kind of a pain.

Comment: Still happening on 3.13 stable

Comment: @JaredEzz im on 3.13.6 and here the warning stoped